How to extract only part of a string based on the first occurrence of a multiple-character delimiter?
Using SQL I need to extract a part of a string from Column1 that is separated in this manner:
IRRELEVANTTEXT - REQUIREDTEXT-MORETEXT - MORETEXT2

The IRRELEVANTTEXT can be of varying lengths, and the delimiter " - " may or may not appear later in the required text. Is there a way to extract all text after the first occurrence of " - " but not remove relevant text that may include the same delimiter later on?
The end result should be:
REQUIREDTEXT-MORETEXT - MORETEXT2


Walk backwards and find the third - in that string? REVERSE-function might be of use there.

I feel it's easier to just remove up to the first delimiter, @siggemannen . I've added an answer to the dupe that uses a different solution to RIGHT, as well to demonstrate.

Oh, i read it that delimiter could appear in "irrelevant text" as well. Oh well, then yeah, it's simple

@siggemannen You read correctly, that delimiter can appear in the relevant part of the text and we would want to keep it in that part.

I think you would have more luck if you specified the example text more exactly, especially the text you have issues with. Because right now, this doesn't look harder than substring(column, charindex('-', column) + 1, 99999)
